# Ensure a view remains full screen upon rotate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, orientation

I have a simple `UIWebView` that I've added to my `UIViewController` in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
self.webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
```

And it looks great, but when I rotate the phone, the width and height remain the same so now it's too wide for the update view frame. I also tried using self.view.bounds, but it didn't make any difference.

So how do you ensure that a view that is fullscreen on load, stays the same size when rotated? (without using IB)

Comment: Is this an iphone or ipad application? You should know the dimensions, so you can just size the view to fill the entire screen on rotate.

Comment: I *CAN* do that, but I was under the impression that I could "anchor" or "dock" the view to the corners so it'll stretch to fill as the underlying view size changes. I'm from a WebForms background so I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is correct & should work in most scenarios. But since I have no idea about your View Stack. I will suggest a sure shot way -

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    CGRect rect;
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft||toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
       rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    }
    else
    {
        //some other dimensions.
    }
     self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because web view not called only once it need to be called again
to set the new frame

```
self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
```

so you have to register notification in viwewillappear or viewdidload

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(viewBecamePortrait:) name:@"orientationIsPortrait" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(viewBecameLandscape:) name:@"orientationIsLandscape" object:nil];



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        NSNotification* notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"orientationIsPortrait" object:self];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];
    }else {
        NSNotification* notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"orientationIsLandscape" object:self];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];
    }
}
```

Then implement

```
-(void)viewBecameLandscape:(id)sender{
    if(webview){
      [webview.setframe(cgrectmake(x,y,width,height))];
    }
}
-(void)viewBecamePortrait:(id)sender{
}
```

Comment: Why using a notification for such trivial 1to1 relationship?